# How to summarize in R the number of first occurrences of a character string in a dataframe column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am trying to figure out a fast way to calculate the number of "first times" a specified character appears in a dataframe column, by groups. In this example, I am trying to summarize (sum) the number of first times, for each `Period`, the `State` of "X" appears, grouped by `ID`. I am looking for a fast way to process this because it is to be run against a database of several million rows. Maybe there is a good solution using the data.table package?

Immediately below I illustrate what I am trying to achieve, and at the bottom I post the code for the dataframe called `testDF`.

[image]

Code:

```
testDF <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c(rep(10,5),rep(50,5),rep(60,5)),
    Period = c(1:5,1:5,1:5),
    State = c("A","B","X","X","X",
              "A","A","A","A","A",
              "A","X","A","X","B")
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe we can group by 'ID' first and then create the column and then do a group by 'period' and `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
testDF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(`1stStateX` = row_number() == which(State == "X")[1]) %>% 
  group_by(Period) %>%
  summarise(`1stStateX` = sum(`1stStateX`, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  Period `1stStateX`
   <int>       <int>
1      1           0
2      2           1
3      3           1
4      4           0
5      5           0
```

---

Another option will be to `slice` after grouping by 'ID', get the `count` and use `complete` to fill the 'Period' not available

```
library(tidyr)
testDF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(match('X', State)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  count(Period, sort = TRUE ,name = "1stStateX") %>% 
  complete(Period = unique(testDF$Period), 
    fill = list(`1stStateX` = 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  Period `1stStateX`
   <int>       <int>
1      1           0
2      2           1
3      3           1
4      4           0
5      5           0
```

---

Or similar option in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(testDF)[, `1stStateX` := .I == .I[State == 'X'][1], 
  ID][, .(`1stStateX` = sum(`1stStateX`, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Period]
```

-output

```
 Period 1stStateX
    <int>     <int>
1:      1         0
2:      2         1
3:      3         1
4:      4         0
5:      5         0
```

Comment: Thank you for laying out several options like this. I'll run some speed tests against the full 2m row file and revert with that feedback.

Comment: Running these 3 options against the 2m+ row database results are as follows: (a) dplyr took 1.918222 seconds, (b) tidyr version took 2.93334 seconds, and (c) data.table took only 0.2997088 seconds.